# overwriting styles using JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm working with a sidebar menu implementation but at the time of page loading, I end up seeing the menu for a brief moment before it disappears. Other than that brief flashing moment, everything else works the way it is expected to be.

So my goal is to eliminate that brief appearance of the menu list items. For that, I came up with this 0px idea.

Please see below where I marked it as `right:0px;  //this used to be 320. But making it 0px, eliminates the flash! )` line.

But of course, this fix introduces another problem... the problem of not seeing the menu when I interact with it, such as clicking on some items which is supposed to show deeper levels...

Anyway, here, I figured that I need to be able to set that `right:0px` back to `right:320px` but I need to do that at the JQuery branch... How do I do that?

This way, at the time of page load, 0px rules.. but when the dom loads, we can turn the 320px back on.

Here are the specific code that are relevant to this issue:

I have this styles in the head section...

```
html.mm-right.mm-opening .mm-page, 
html.mm-right.mm-opening #mm-blocker, 
html.mm-right.mm-opening .mm-fixed-top, 
html.mm-right.mm-opening .mm-fixed-bottom {
    right: 0px;  //this used to be 320. But making it 0px, eliminates the flash! ) 
}
```

And I have this jQuery init at the footer:

//  The menu on the right

```
jQuery(function() {

    var $menu = jQuery('nav#menu-right');

    $menu.mmenu({
        position    : 'right',
        classes     : 'mm-light',
        dragOpen    : true,
        counters    : true,
        searchfield : true,
        labels      : {
            fixed       : !jQuery.mmenu.support.touch
        },
        header      : {
            add         : true,
            update      : true,
            title       : 'IslamiCity '
        }
    });

    //document.write ('<style>html.mm-right.mm-opening .mm-page, html.mm-right.mm-opening #mm-blocker, html.mm-right.mm-opening .mm-fixed-top, html.mm-right.mm-opening .mm-fixed-bottom {right: 320px;}</style>'); //tried that but did not help! 


    //  Click a menu-item
    var $confirm = jQuery('#confirmation');
    $menu.find( 'li a' ).not( '.mm-subopen' ).not( '.mm-subclose' ).bind(
        'click.example',
        function( e )
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            $confirm.show().text( 'You clicked "' + jQuery.trim( jQuery(this).text() ) + '"' );
            jQuery('#menu-right').trigger( 'close' );
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you set the container to display none for page load you can then remove that after all the other scripts run and set up the menu.

you could then show it using something like

```
$('#menu-right').show();
$('#menu-right').css('display','block');
```

should do it

Comment: menu is wrapped into `<nav id="menu-right">` and `</nav>`. I can add `#menu-right{display:none}` to the header styles... but then how do I remove that when other scripts are done loading?

Comment: @AverageJoe, just edited my answer to show you how to remove. you may need to change from display block to whatever you need it to be.

Comment: Thanks workabyte however, when I do those lines, I get the opened-up-menu displayed in its full glory - as soon as the dom is complete. That's a problem cause menu should ONLY be opened up upon a click event on the menu icon. Is there a way to do something like onclick="$(#menu-right').show();$('#menu-'right').css('display','block');" on that menu icon so that your code runs only upon a click?

Comment: @AverageJoe, are you sure you even need to remove them when the scripts are done. i think whatever code is setting up the menu to hide and show should do that for you. try it omitting them.